# What is ..vimrc.un~ and which Vim component creates it why?

Tags: vim, vimrc

As of late I often find a file named `..vimrc.un~` in the folder in which I edit a file. Where does this file come from?

I am using Vim 7.3 with plugins `pathogen`, `nerdtree`, `vim-eunuch`, `vim-surround`, `vim-sparkup` and `vim-sensible`.

Note: the reason I ask is because I don't know yet what particular component causes it. Otherwise I would be able to dig deeper or ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those files are used to store information for storing persistent undo 
information, allowing changes to be undone even after quitting and restarting 
vim.  This is a builtin feature of vim, not from any plugin.

You can get additional information about this from within vim with:

```
:help undo-persistence
:help 'undofile'
:help 'undodir'
```

Comment: Which setting and/or command line switch prevents the behavior? Is this the same as `-n`? Thanks for the answer for now and +1

Comment: This is controlled by the `undofile` option, the second help section that I referenced.  This is different than the swap files controlled by the `-n` option.

Comment: Aaah, thanks. Means `vim-sensible` is the culprit and not so sensible for me after all ;)

Comment: My issue is that I had `set undodir=$HOME/.vimtmp/,.` but that directory did not exist. So instead, it was putting the undofile right next to the original file.